# Why majority of synthesized mRNAs are halted at Nuclear Pore Complex?

Tags: transcription, mrna, membrane-transport

I was reading about mRNA export process. I came to know that only [36%](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1046202318300938) of synthesized mRNA transport events at Nuclear Pore Complexes(NPC) of the nuclear membrane get successful in crossing to the cytoplasm. I have heard that transcription machinery is a highly accurate one and so why would NPCs want to regulate mRNA transport like this?

- Is NPC acting as a quality checker? Are there any errors mRNAs facing in between the transcription and meeting NPCs? (Please share related literature, if you find some.)
- Any other hypothesis someone would want to share?

Comment: I think this is so specific that you might want to consider contacting the authors directly, they've probably been thinking about this since their paper in 2013 found the same fraction of mRNAs unable to cross the NPC

Comment: One thought, upon re-reading. It says 36% of events are successful. This doesn't mean that 64% of mRNPs never cross, it just means that out of every 100 attempts to cross, 36% are sucessful. Perhaps most of the 64% that failed simply try again later and succeed?

Comment: @Thymine my bad. Should I delete the question?